# Numpy - Calculating product of a diagonal

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Newbie question:  assuming I have a matrix A, is there a numpy function which will calculate the product of the diagonal elements of A?

EG:

[image]

Where, X(i,i) is the diagonal product of the matrix.

Comment: `np.diag(X).prod()`?

Comment: I prefer the functional programming approach of prod however :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `diagonal` and `prod` methods:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.matrix([[1, 1, 1],
             [1, 2, 3],
             [3, 3, 3]])

prod_diag = a.diagonal().prod()
print(prod_diag)
# gives 6 as answer
```

`diagonal` returns the diagonal components of the matrix as a 1D array and `prod` calculates the product of all the elements of the array.